# How to show/print same content twice or more using drupal_view in a template?

Tags: twig, drupal-8, drupal-views

I have a page where I need to show/print the same content twice. For this, I am using drupal_view.

```
{{ drupal_view('product_content', 'page_1', node.id) }}
```

This code works only for the first position and for the second position it doesn't work. What can be done so that the content shows up in both places?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is good practice but you could assign the output to a variable and render the variable multiple times. `{% set resp = drupal_view(.....) %}`

Comment: @DarkBee I follow what you suggested but still the same thing. Getting the expected result for the first div but not for the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution from the Drupal community:

When something is rendered, the render system remembers what has been
rendered and won't re-render that. Assign the render output to a twig
variable and print the variable twice:

```
> {% set product_content = drupal_view( ... )|render %}
> {{ product_content }} 
> {{ product_content }}
```